# Is it possible to play a game on one computer in a LAN while using the graphics and processing power of another computer in the same LAN?

Tags: graphics-card, streaming

I have a simple home server and I'm planning on buying a new GPU for my regular desktop. I was thinking about plugging the old GPU in my server and hosting some kind of game-streaming thing on it for visitors with crappy laptops. The thing is, all the solutions I found for this require you to install a certain game on the server and then stream it to the client with their software. But that's not what I want, I want guests to be able to play games they have installed on their client using my server's power. This way I don't have to go into the server for every new game.

Comment: Are you saying you want to somehow "stream" your server's GPU capabilities? I don't think that's possible. There are ways to hook up an external graphics card to a laptop, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: So basically what Steam does? Windows 10 does with Xbox One Games, Nvidiea Shield does...

Comment: @Ramhound As far as I know you need steam and the game installed on the serving machine to stream like that, same with xbox and shield. I don't want to install anything on the server after the initial setup, I also don't want to be limited to a library of games.

Comment: @Kevin You can add any game or program to Steam and then stream it. I had a PS2 emulator I was running on a craptop being streamed from a PC through Steam and it worked well. What you could do is have them log on to a steam profile you've set up that contains a library of games (Steam or Non-Steam) and have them stream them from there.

What you're looking for is currently impossible.

Comment: @Kevin - You asked if its possible.  A user replied they didn't think it was possible.  I provided 3 different examples of it being possible.  This is possible you just have to write the software, or use the software that exists, to do it.

Comment: @Ramhound I know very well that streaming games is possible, what I asked was if it's also possible without installing the game on the server.

Comment: @Kevin - No; That isn't possible.  That has never been possible.  At the core of the idea is a critical flaw, the server must have the file, to stream something that is a universal truth.